# Mediawiki / TinyMCE Extension : add custom button

Tags: javascript, mediawiki, tinymce-4, mediawiki-extensions

I'm using Mediawiki 1.30 + TinyMCE extension( https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TinyMCE)

TinyMCE version in this extension is 4.6.4.

I want to add my own custom button to the editor by following that guide: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/custom-toolbar-button/

I'm adding the code to that file in my mediawiki install folder : extensions/TinyMCE/MW_tinymce.js

I added at the right place:

```
setup: function(editor) {
    alert('blabla');
    editor.addButton('mybutton', {
    text: 'My button',
    icon: false,
    onclick: function () {
     editor.insertContent('&nbsp;<b>It\'s my button!</b>&nbsp;');
    }
});
```

And disable the mediawiki cache for debugging purpose, i put in LocalSettings.php:

```
$wgResourceLoaderDebug = true;
```

So when i open a page with the TinyMCE Editor, the alert 'blabla' popups but no custom button is added to the editor. (no javascript error in console)

Could you please help me about that? Did I forget anything important?

(by the way i also tried to do that after TinyMCE init but that doesnt work)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it...

You have to add your button identifier 'mybutton' in the 'toolbar' attributes:

```
toolbar1: 'undo redo | cut copy paste insert | bold italic underline strikethrough subscript superscript forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | charmap singlelinebreak wikilink unlink table wikiupload wikimagic wikisourcecode | formatselect removeformat | searchreplace fontsizeselect mybutton',
```